# How do I retrieve a image from a rss entry?

Tags: uitableview, ios5, xcode4.2, tablerow

I'm currently working on a news app and would really like to add a image to a table row of the image for the news article.

I have managed to parse everything else, it's just I can't parse the image url.

This is the code I used for striping the HTML from the feed.

.M file

```
- (NSString *)stringByStrippingHTML:(NSString *)inputString 
{
NSMutableString *outString;

if (inputString)
{
    outString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:inputString];

    if ([inputString length] > 0)
    {
        NSRange r;

        while ((r = [outString rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [outString deleteCharactersInRange:r];
        }      
    }
}

return outString;
```

}

.H file

```
- (NSString *)stringByStrippingHTML:(NSString *)inputString;
```

I'm quite new to xcode and code in general so I'm not familiar in this stuff.

I just can't figure out in parsing the url for the image.

This is the code for the tablerow appearance.

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=3;
cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines=4;


RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSString *articleDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:entry.articleDate];

NSString * articleDescrptionString = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];
articleDescrptionString = entry.articleDescription;

cell.textLabel.text = entry.articleTitle; 

NSString *plainString = [self stringByStrippingHTML:entry.articleDescription ];

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: entry.articleImageUrl];

//NSString *rangedString = [plainString substringToIndex:249];  //0 to 249 makes it 250 characters

//cell.detailTextLabel.text = articleDescrptionString;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", articleDateString, plainString];

//UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:entry.articleImageUrl];
//cell.imageView.image = theImage;

return cell;
}
```

Any code I've commented out is currently not used at the moment at it's not used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Load the Image into a NSData object first...

```
NSURL *imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:entry.articleImageUrl];
NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgURL];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
```

But you will have to do it asynchronously, because if you do it without a lazy image load you TableView will be stocking while scrolling...